# Error: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: postgresql

```
saleco_dw=> SELECT s.cus_code AS Customer_Code, r.reg_name AS Region_Name, (s.sale_price*s.sale_units) AS Total_Sales
FROM dwdaysalesfact s, dwregion r
LEFT JOIN dwcustomer c
ON c.cus_code = s.cus_code
ORDER BY r.reg_name, c.cus_code;

ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "s"

LINE 4: ON c.cus_code = s.cus_code
                        ^

HINT:  There is an entry for table "s", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be combining the outdated implicit joins with "modern" (nearly 30 years old) explicit JOIN operators. And your query is a very good example why the implicit join is so fragile: you did forget the join condition between `dwdaysalesfact`  and `dwregion`.

The root cause of your error is the mixing of join styles changes - it changes the priority on how table (aliases) are seen and can be used.

So rewrite it to use proper JOINs and the reference in the LEFT JOIN gest to be valid:

```
SELECT s.cus_code AS Customer_Code, 
       r.reg_name AS Region_Name, 
       (s.sale_price*s.sale_units) AS Total_Sales
FROM dwdaysalesfact s
  JOIN dwregion r ON s.??? = r.???
  LEFT JOIN dwcustomer c ON c.cus_code = s.cus_code
ORDER BY r.reg_name, c.cus_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

The ON is just telling how to join r to c, so references to s there are not allowed.  I can't tell you how to fix it, as I don't know what you actually want to happen.

But combining comma joins and explicit joins in the same FROM is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be missing a join or where clause to include the dwregion table you are aliasing in the FROM statement.

```
SELECT 
    s.cus_code AS Customer_Code, 
    r.reg_name AS Region_Name, 
    (s.sale_price*s.sale_units) AS Total_Sales 
FROM dwdaysalesfact s, dwregion r  -- how are you intending to use r?
LEFT JOIN dwcustomer c ON c.cus_code = s.cus_code 
ORDER BY r.reg_name, c.cus_code;
```